# Python - Command line arguments without [ ' ' ]

Tags: python

I probably have conjured up some sloppy code trying to get this resolved but what I really want to accomplish is take an IP Address from the command line and fit it into a string variable (theargis).

I am working with a code snippet to assure myself that I have the code worked out before integrating it into my main program, so I am printing the result to the screen.

It is working as such, but the problem is that I am seeing ['123.123.123.123'] instead of 123.123.123.123.

I have tried several ways to attempt to convert the list value in to a raw string without additional formatting, but I am losing the battle.

The question is how I get the final line of this to produce: The argument is: 123.123.123.123

Here is what I have right now...

```
import sys
theargis = ''

theargis +=str(sys.argv[1:])
print ("The argument is: " + theargis)
```

I'm fairly sure I am displaying just how green I am to Python but I want to resolve this!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import sys
theargis = ''

theargis +=str(sys.argv[1])
print ("The argument is: " + theargis)
```

Comment: Going to flag this as the answer, but I am more confused now because I don't see where the code you posted is any different than what I was using. BUT!!! I copied it and pasted it into the script and it returns exactly what I want.

Comment: NOW I see it! Lose the : after the 1... Thanks!